# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel;xxxxxxxxxx }

Tags: java, android, firebase

** android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9rZy.png)**** its is firebase databse seytem**
i have a button ther when i click the button app was crass and send me the error
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

```
.kazimasum.firebasefragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class descfragment extends Fragment {
    private Button callBtn;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    String name, course, email, purl, call;
    public descfragment() {

    }

    public descfragment(String name, String course, String email, String purl, String call) {
        this.name=name;
        this.course=course;
        this.email=email;
        this.purl=purl;
        this.call=call;
    }

    public static descfragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        descfragment fragment = new descfragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_descfragment, container, false);
        Button callBtn=view.findViewById(R.id.callBtn);
        ImageView imageholder=view.findViewById(R.id.imagegholder);
        TextView nameholder=view.findViewById(R.id.nameholder);
        TextView courseholder=view.findViewById(R.id.courseholder);
        TextView emailholder=view.findViewById(R.id.emailholder);
        final TextView callholder=view.findViewById(R.id.callholder);
        callBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                 String s = "tel" + call;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(s));
                startActivity(intent);




            }
        });
        nameholder.setText(name);
        courseholder.setText(course);
        emailholder.setText(email);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(purl).into(imageholder);
        callholder.setText(call);


        return  view;



    }



    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        AppCompatActivity activity=(AppCompatActivity)getContext();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrapper,new recfragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();




    }
```

Comment: `tel` should be followed by a colon (`:`), not a semicolon (`;`). Also, bear in mind that you need the `CALL_PHONE` permission and that not every Android device is a phone.

Comment: Did CommonsWare's comment solve the issue?